# I installed Ubuntu but then on the restart it still gives me the option to install it

Tags: system-installation, 14.10, system

Is this normal or is there some thing wrong?  The installation options are still on the desktop.  I had selected the restart now option.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed it from USB flash drive, turn your PC off and remove the flash drive from USB port; then turn it on again – it should boot normally.

And also one question: as you've specified in the tags here, you've installed Ubuntu 14.10. Are you really sure that you need this version? The matter is that Ubuntu 14.10 will be supported only until July 2015, so I'd recommend you to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: it will be supported until April 2019.

Comment: Oh thank you I will install the 14.04 LTS version.  Also I had not removed the USB.